# ASP.NET WebMethod not called

Tags: jquery, asp.net

please help me to solve this. I can't make webmethod work.

Default.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

and Default.aspx.cs:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetData()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

I get 401 unauthorized error response.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: put `[ScriptService]` top of the class.

Comment: what error you get in your console ?

Comment: @ShreeKhanal thanks but not working.

Comment: @umer i get nothing. can you show a way to find error?

Comment: There's no error in your console ? before sending the ajax call does an alert work. put an alert before and after sending the ajax call and see if alert occurs

Comment: `[WebMethod(true)]` also help some time other wise there is no fault in your code.

Comment: @umer, yes ia have done that before. the alert works when i comment the json function and only alert inside the ajax call and it works but other than that , nothing works

Comment: also, i have created another clean project and that does not work either

Comment: Then you must see an error in your console.

Comment: @umer the returned string is like this: url:"http://localhost:60140/Default.aspx/GetUnreadMessages" and success:"true" so it is executed correctly i guess, but nothing happens

Comment: but response code is 401

Comment: Response code 401 depicts your issue .. This is authentication related issue ..

Comment: @umer, and what does that mean? can you please explain?

Comment: In your browser console go to the network tab , refresh the page , watch in the network tab and there would showing all of the requests which your page makes to the server. Call  to your webmethod (GetData) would also be showing in there. click on that and watch the response of of that call. That would be a detailed description of what happened with your ajax call.

Comment: There can be lots of reasons for that. Read this blog for instance

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/many-time-401-unauthorized-on-ajax-requests

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your web config file,

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
</system.web>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, just 401 unauthorized error code again

Comment: Are you trying this on a local machine ? or in a different server?

Comment: local machine but i tried in another server and the same result

Comment: <authorization>
        <allow users="*" /> 
 </authorization> . Try adding this also